# Is there an rspec for belongs_to_active_hash, same as belongs_to :other_model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rspec, matcher

I have many active record validations which work ok, such as this:
code: `belongs_to :topics`
test: `it { should belong_to :topic }`

However I have an active_hash association and a test like this:

code:  `belongs_to_active_hash :day`
test:  `pending { should belong_to_active_hash :day }`

but the tests fails:

undefined method `if' for #<Shoulda::Matchers`...

Answer (score 0):

Shoulda doesn't have support for ActiveHash matchers. You can test this manually:

```
  specify do 
     reflection = YourModel.reflect_on_association(:day)
     options = {} # options you passed to belongs_to_active_hash

     reflection.should_not be_nil
     reflection.macro.should eq :belongs_to
     reflection.options.should eq options
  end
```

If you use this often, you can create a custom matcher.